# XCode Unit & UI Tests strategies/how to

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing

I just started getting into writing unit tests via Xcode for an application I'm writing and so far it all seems pretty easy. However this is an unfortunately small amount of things to read about `XCTest` and related classes on the web so I'm left with a couple of questions.

1) When testing massively complex structures such as a view controller, what do you test? My view controllers, for example, have outlets, view models, custom subview classes, and so on. So far I'm just testing the `IBOutlets` and that I can load the view controller from a storyboard instance.

2) Should custom view classes be tested on their own? For some views this makes sense (subclasses of buttons, text fields, etc) because their view controller independent but what about with highly custom classes, say an `OnboardingView` that's a property on an `OnboardingViewController` instance.

3) Finally, what are the practical use cases for `XCTestSuite`? My intuition would be if I wanted to group similar tests together, say ones for all my view controllers, and then run just that test suite via some automation tool like Jenkins.